# macOS Catalina: "file already exists, replace it?" popup, how to select Replace with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, shortcut, dialog, highlights

When trying to save a file that already exists, macOS typically shows the "File already exists, replace it?" popup, like this:

[image: Cancel Replace popup]

In previous versions of macOS (like Mojave, High Sierra, etc) I was always able to choose either `Cancel` or `Replace` **using the keyboard**.

However since Catalina, it doesn't seem to be working. As displayed in the screenshot above, the `Cancel` button is highlighted by default. If I press the <kbd>Return</kbd> key it will choose `Cancel`. However I used to be able to switch between `Cancel` and `Replace` by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. But not anymore.

Also tried the cursor left and right keys (<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>) but to no avail.

This particular example is from macOS' default Preview app, but it's the same in pretty much any application.

Also in some applications I could previously use something like <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to choose either the left or right option respectively (`Cancel` or `Replace` in this case) but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Is there a different keyboard shortcut or combination of buttons nowadays? Or do I really HAVE to use the mouse to choose `Replace` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a different keyboard shortcut or combination of buttons nowadays?

In **macOS Catalina**, using a *keyboard shortcut* to **Replace** instead of **Cancel** when confronted with a **... Do you want to replace it?** *sheet*, press: **⌘R**

Answer (score 4):

Make sure this is on In System Preferences >> Keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I see I can now also use [space] to choose the other option! 